# Is it possible to buffer an audio file right before play on react-native-video?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to play youtube videos as audio file in react-native-video with link gathered from react-native-ytdl. It is starts playing but I'm not unable to seek forward or backward. Is there any way to buffer audio file in memory? So maybe I can seek forward/backward with that method.

I am open to another solutions aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue with changing my code to this;

```
const urls = await ytdl(youtubeURL, { filter: format => format.container === 'mp4' , quality: 'highestaudio', highWaterMark: 1024 * 1024 * 14 });
```

ytdl was using .webm for default and react-native-video can't buffer(or seek) .webm files but it is okay with mp4 now.